# How to paint 5 days in a calendar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm getting the start date of a workday from a database, so I can display it on a calendar.

In the calendar you should only show the start date plus 7 days and these should be in a different color to know that this is your work week.

How can I do it? I have the following

```
 private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  
    {   
        if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
        {                
            DataTable asistencia = OperadoresAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];     
            if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
                string Tipo = iRow["Tipo"].ToString();
                Tipo = asistencia.Rows[0]["Tipo"].ToString();
                DateTime FechaJornada = DateTime.Now;               
                string FechaJ = FechaJornada.AddDays(8).ToShortDateString();
                TextBox1.Text = FechaJ;
                    if (Tipo == "1")                    
                {
                   e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code?  Is there an error?  Does it run fine but just not give you the desired result?

Comment: I mark the whole calendar in one color.
I want you to mark me just color the DateJornada and add 7 more days.

Comment: How can I make it just check the date that comes from my database and not the whole calendar

Comment: Any examples that may be useful?